# ActionFilter - OnActionExecuted is called AFTER Json result returned

Tags: json, action-filter

I'm creating a plugin within another framework, so I don't have ability to change the controller. I have an Actionfilter making changes to the model in OnActionExecuted.  This works fine when the controller returns a View.  However, if the page uses AJAX and the controller returns a JSON result using an implementation of RenderPartialViewToString, the result (model) is returned to the client prior to the OnActionExecuted.

I've stepped through the code in the debugger.
This is the sequence when returning a View:

```
 OnActionExecuting

 controller's ActionResult SomeMethod()
   return View(...

 OnActionExecuted

 SomeView.cshtml
```

This is the sequence when using AJAX:

```
 OnActionExecuting

 controller ActionResult SomeMethod()
   return Json(...  html = this.RenderPartialViewToString("...", myModel)

 SomeView.cshtml

 OnActionExecuted
```

Any thoughts on how I can modify the model prior to it being returned in partial view?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `RenderPartialViewToString("...", myModel)`. You directly render it before returning result from action. Method `OnActionExecuted` is invoked after controller action returns.

When you `return View(...)` it is not render this View. It is return model and say that this model to current view. Rendering of view will be later.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Is there some way to work around it?

Comment: Could you show this SomeView.cshtml? Why are you generate json with View against JavascriptSerializer?

Comment: As I indicated above "I'm creating a plugin within another framework...".   It's nopCommerce; the view is here http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/be37c2a1b232#src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Checkout/OpcPaymentMethods.cshtml .  I want to modify the model before it gets to the view.

Comment: If you want to simple modify your model, create method and use it on model before passing model to RenderPartialViewToString(...).